# MySQL Group two column with where clause on both two group

Tags: mysql, group-by

***What I have:***
I have two table , first is `user_faktorha` save invoices data and second is `u_payment` save payment data .

***What I want:***
I want to group all data from this two table and have a result as one table with sum both table.
My two table with sample query's is on sqlfiddle : http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/b9f9e/4

***What's problem:***
I try to solve this problem , but give wrong result each time , for example (can be see on sqlfiddle) , user/tell named as `habib` on give wrong sum(price) result.

`habib's faktorhaprice = -508261 and habib's paymentprice = 648000` but sum result in main query have wrong data `-7115654 and 13000000`

**what's the solution ?**

Comment: In your SQLFiddle for the u_payment table alone you are restricting rows selected to those `WHERE Active='1'`, but in your main query you have omitted this restriction - do you want the main query to include this restriction on u_payment records too?

Comment: yes , must be include in main query . but I don't know how to do it :) , left it alone on main .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

(Updated) One way:

```
SELECT tell,SUM(FAKTORHAPRICE) FAKTORHAPRICE, SUM(PaymentPrice) PaymentPrice 
FROM (SELECT tell, price as FAKTORHAPRICE, null PaymentPrice
      from user_faktorha
      union all
      SELECT Username as tell, null as FAKTORHAPRICE, Price as PaymentPrice
      FROM `u_payment` WHERE Active='1') sq 
GROUP BY tell ORDER BY FAKTORHAPRICE ASC;
```

SQLFiddle [here](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/b9f9e/23).

Comment: Thanks Mark , but give wrong result on paymentprice , see at : http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/b9f9e/17

Comment: Thanks mark , that's now work successfully . but if it's possible : main query what must to have a total price with sum `Faktorhaprice` and `Paymentprice` as one column and order by this total sum ?

Comment: @root: See http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/b9f9e/27 for a combined total in addition to the two separate total values - or did you want it instead of them?

Answer (score 0):

The essence of your problem here is that you are trying to relate to unrelated tables.  Sure they have common data in the user name, but there is not a clean relation between them like an invoice id that can be used to relate the items together such that the OUTER JOIN wouldn't duplicate records in your result set.  My suggestion would be to do the aggregation on each table individually and then join the results like this:

```
SELECT f.tell, f.faktorhaprice, p.paymentprice
FROM
    (SELECT tell, SUM(price) AS faktorhaprice FROM user_faktorha GROUP BY tell) AS f
INNER JOIN
    (SELECT username, SUM(price) AS paymentprice FROM u_payment GROUP BY username) AS p
ON f.tell = p.username
```